# StructureMap Configuration Issue with MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, structuremap

I'm trying to get an existing MVC4 app running on a new machine but encountering the issue:

[image]

The installed version of MVC4 is:

[image]

It appears there is a problem with the compatibility of MVC and Structure map,  but I cannot see the difference between the installations on the working and non-working machines.

Has anyone experienced this issue or have a suggestion of what might resolve it? Please ask if more info is required about versions and other installed software.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by installing "StructureMap.MVC4" version 3.0.2.115 from NuGet.